# crack this code #1965

Tags: mastermind

Using the clues provided, determine the 'password'.

`501` — Two correct numbers in wrong places
`135` — One correct number in the right place
`483` — All numbers are wrong
`167` — One correct number in wrong place
`430` — One correct number in the wrong place

Comment: +1 for reminding me that I haven't played Mastermind in a while...such a fun game.

Comment: While Mastermind technically has 4 digits, I figured it was close enough that tagging it wouldn't be too off-putting. Glad I reminded you of the game. :)

Answer (score 12):

```
[5, 0, 1]: 2  
[1, 3, 5]: 1
```

> So either 5 or 1 is correct, but not both.

```
[4, 8, 3]: none.

[1, 6, 7]: 1
```

> Because 1 is in the same place as it was before, but the "one correct" is in the wrong place, it cannot be a right number. This means that `5` (from earlier) is definitely the last number, and also one of either 6 or 7 is correct, but in the wrong place.

```
[4, 3, 0]:
```

> We know from above that 4 and 3 are both wrong, and we deduced from the last step that 1 was not a number, meaning the first line shows us that 5 and 0 are both numbers, so this actually gives us no new information on which numbers, but does tell us that 0 is *still* in the wrong place. 
>  
>  This means that we have "0 x 5" with x being either 6 or 7. From the second-last line, we know that the correct number is in the wrong place, so it can't be 6 (which was in the middle). 
>  
>  The final answer is: **0 7 5**.

Comment: I think it's awesome that you got to the conclusion relatively simply, but didn't get there by the much more important piece of info those first two rules gave: switching from 0 to 3 gave one less correct number - which means 0 *has* to be one of the three numbers (and, conversely, 3 cannot.)

Answer (score 4):

The following are my musings to find the answer:

Starting with 430 (Rule 5):

> `4??` Eliminated by rule 5
>  `?4?` Eliminated by rule 3
>  `??4` Eliminated by rule 3
>  `3??` Eliminated by rule 3
>  `?3?` Eliminated by rule 5
>  `??3` Eliminated by rule 3
>  `0??` Remaining - Now Rule 6
>  `?0?` Remaining - Now Rule 6
>  `??0` Eliminated by rule 5

Starting with 501 (Rule 1):

> `5?1` Eliminated by rule 1
>  `51?` Eliminated by rule 1
>  `15?` Eliminated by rule 6
>  `1?5` Eliminated by rule 2
>  `?15` Eliminated by rule 6
>  `?51` Eliminated by rule 1
>  `50?` Eliminated by rule 1
>  `5?0` Eliminated by rule 1
>  `?50` Eliminated by rule 2
>  `?05` Eliminated by rule 1
>  `0?5` Remaining - Now Rule 7
>  `05?` Eliminated by rule 2
>  `?01` Eliminated by rule 1
>  `?10` Eliminated by rule 2
>  `1?0` Eliminated by rule 6
>  `10?` Eliminated by rule 1
>  `01?` Eliminated by rule 2
>  `0?1` Eliminated by rule 1

Starting with 167 (Rule 4):

> `1??` Elimated by rule 4
>  `?1?` Elimated by rule 1
>  `??1` Elimated by rule 7
>  `6??` Elimated by rule 7
>  `?6?` Elimated by rule 4
>  `??6` Elimated by rule 7
>  `7??` Elimated by rule 7
>  `?7?` Remaining - Now Rule 8
>  `??7` Elimated by rule 4

Combining the two new rules, 7 and 8 gives:

> Result `075`

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answers too complicate, so I share mine. **Only three rules are needed**:

**501 — Two correct numbers in wrong places**

> So, only one of those numbers should be removed. Which one?

**135 — One correct number in the right place**

> Since this shares 2 numbers with the first one, the 3 cannot be the
>  correct one. (If the 3 comes into play, the rule would give info about
>  2 numbers instead of one). So, from the previous rule, we should
>  remove only the 1 or the 5.  Now we know the number has a 0 in one side,
>  and starts with 1 or end with 5. Only 2 chances: 1_0 or 0_5.

**167 — One correct number in wrong place**

> This number start with 1 as the previous one, and the 1 can't be in
>  right and wrong place at the same time. So, we have only one
>  possibility now: 0_5. We are only missing the middle number and can't be the
>  6 because it's already in the middle and not in the right place. So
>  the only option left is the 7. -> **075**.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! I'm a little confused on your answer for 501, can you elaborate more?

Comment: Excellent observation about the 3 to get it down to three rules!

Answer (score 3):

Answer Should be

> 075

because

> 0 Is right because there are two numbers right in first condition. And other one is wrong because of second condition in which 5 or 1 Has to be wrong. and From last condition 0 is selected and other 2 values got discard because of the 3rd condition. We got the position of the 0 from these two upper conditions. as 0 is wrong at second place in first condition and 0 is also wrong at last place in last condition.
> 5 Is selected from first condition if we select 1 then we get only 2 numbers as we need 3 to make the key. 5 is also right in condition second in which we also got the right position of the 5.
> 7 is right because of 4th condition as the other two number which is 1 is wrong due to first and second condition because we selected 5 and 6 is also wrong due to the position of 6. we need number that fits in position between 5 and 0. because 7 is at wrong place that fits at second position.
> As it satisfy all conditions
> 501 — Two correct numbers in wrong places(5,0, As 1 or 5 get discard in second condition, so i took 5)
> 135 — One correct number in the right place(5, As we can select only one that should be from first condition.)
> 483 — All numbers are wrong(If presented above shall be discard.)
> 167 — One correct number in wrong place(7, Both the last and first place is booked thats why only chance 7)
> 430 — One correct number in the wrong place(0, as we took in the first step.)

Answer (score 2):

Only the first four rules are necessary to find the answer.

> a. Via rules 2 & 3 the answer contains a 1 or a 5 but not both.
>  b. Via (a), rule 1, and rule 2 the 1 or 5 in the answer is not in the middle.
>  c. Rules 2 and 4 contradict if 1 is in the number, so 1 is not in the number, **therefore 5 is at the end**.
>  d. Via (b), (c), and rule 1 the answer contains a 0 which is not in the middle, **therefore 0 is at the front**.
>  e. Via (c), (d), and rule 4, **7 is in the middle**.
>  The answer is **075**

Answer (score 2):

I will share my process:

- Notes      of format `!5 | !0 | !1` means that the first position can't be 5, second can't be 0, etc.
- *Possible* is short for values which are possible and also have been previously discussed
- Impossible represents values which have been ruled out
- Definite represents values which have been confirmed to exist, though makes no statement on order
- Conditions represent restrictions on password.  For example: `!(1+4)` means the code cannot contain both one and 4

**Step one:**

> `!5 | !0 | !1`
>
>     `Possible: 0,1,5`
>     `Conditions: !(0+1+5)`

**Step Two**

> `!3!5 | !0!1!5 | !1!3`
>      `Possible: 0,1,3,5`
>      `Conditions: !(1+3+5)!(0+1+5)!(1+3)!(1+5)!(3+5)`

**Step Three**

> `!5 | !0!1!5 | !1`
>     `Possible: 0,1,5`
>     `Impossible: 3,4,8 -> as defined`
>     `Conditions: !(0+1+5)`

**Step Four**

> `!1!5 | !0!1!5!6 | !1!7 -> 1 is eliminated`
>     `Possible: 0,5,6,7`
>     `Impossible: 1,3,4,8`
>     `Conditions: !(1+6+7)!(1+6)!(1+7)!(6+7)`

**Step Five**

> `!5 | !0!5!6 | !7 -> !5 | 7 | !7 -> 6 is eliminated here, as explained in below:`
>     `Possible: 0,5,6,7`
>     `Impossible: 1,3,4,8`
>     `Conditions: !(6+7) -> since the middle term requires 7 (!0!5!6), and !(6+7), 6 is removed`

**Conclusion**

> `Possible: 0,5,7`
>     `First Term: !5 -> 0 (since 7 is second term)`
>     `Second Term: 7`
>     `Third Term: 5`
>     .
>     `0 7 5`

Answer (score 1):

1) 501
2) 1X5 — 3 gets eliminated by the next clue
3) XXX — All eliminated
4) X67 — 1 gets eliminated for being in the "wrong" place here but the "right place" on Clue 2
5) XX0 — 4 and 3 gets eliminated by clue 3, leaving 0

> So 0 is in the 1st position, because of the first clue that says it can't be in 2nd

2) XX5 — The 0 took the 1's place, so only 5 is left

> So we have 0X5 at this point.

4) XX7 — 1 gets eliminated by clues 1 and 2, and 6 would be in the "right" place if it was one of the numbers

> Answer: 075

Answer (score 1):

> Rule 1) 501 — Two correct numbers in wrong places
>    Rule 2) 135 — One correct number in the right place
>    Rule 3) 483 — All numbers are wrong
>    Rule 4) 167 — One correct number in wrong place
>    Rule 5) 430 — One correct number in the wrong place

Starting from the most elimination Rule 3

> Because of Rule 3, Rule 5 proves that 0 is at position 1 or 2.
>   But 0 can't be at position 2 because of Rule 1.
>
>   So 0 is at position 1.

Finding the 2nd digit

> Because of Rule 1, and we know about 0, it has to contain a 1 or a 5, but not both.
>   And because of Rule 2, it can't be 1 because that position is already taken by 0.
>
>   So 5 is at position 3.

The remaining digit

> Then there's only the 2nd position to figure out.
>  And because of Rule 4, it can't be 6.
>  The 1 had already been discarded when we discovered 5 is at position 3.
>
>  So 7 is at position 2.

Conclusion:

> 0 7 5

Answer (score 1):

The required password is

> 075 .

Comment: please explain your approach to this answer. thanks and happy puzzling ;)